# How do we Retrive Data Which is Saved By Using Core Data in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios5

I am New to Core Data.I have Developed an application. In my application i am having Registration, Login, Forgot password Forms.

In Registration Form i Write this code for registration.

```
NSEntityDescription *entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSManagedObject *newuser = [[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entitydesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

[newuser setValue:self.registerUsername.text forKey:@"username"];
[newuser setValue:self.registerPassword.text forKey:@"password"];
[newuser setValue:self.registerConfirmPassword.text forKey:@"confirmpassword"];
[newuser setValue:self.registerMobileNumber.text forKey:@"mobilenumber"];

NSError *error;
[context save:&error];
```

In Login Form i write this Code:

```
NSEntityDescription *entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:entitydesc];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username like %@ and password like %@",self.logUsername.text,self.logPassword.text];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *matchingData = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if(matchingData.count<=0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"Username and password does not match" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];

    }
    else
    {
        NSString *username;
        NSString *password;
        for(NSManagedObject *obj in matchingData)
        {
            username = [obj valueForKey:@"username"];
            password = [obj valueForKey:@"password"];
        }
        SecurityHome *securityhome = [[SecurityHome alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:securityhome animated:YES];
    }

}
```

Both were Working fine. Now i want to Display Password in Forgot password page if the user entered Username and Mobile number Correctly.How Can i Achieve this?

Comment: Hopefully never. You better store the passwords encrypted and if the user forgets his password you send him a new one. But i would not use an app which stores my plain password in the database...

Comment: I am with Dehlen for this. You really should not do this. Any how, you might need this info for other purpose, so i've given answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

Set example predicate and sort orderings...

```
NSNumber *minimumSalary = ...;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
@"(lastName LIKE[c] 'Worsley') AND (salary > %@)", minimumSalary];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
[sortDescriptor release];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (array == nil)
{
    // Deal with error...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have done some 'googling' before asking this question. Any how,Let me do it for you. Here you go.
[Core Data NSFetchResult guide for developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html)

[Ray wenderlich- Really nice tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

In both of the listed links, I am trying to suggest NSFetchResultControllers, as they are fast & easy. Here you can see the difference
Without NSFetchResultController,
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
        entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

```
// Set example predicate and sort orderings...
NSNumber *minimumSalary = ...;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"(lastName LIKE[c] 'Worsley') AND (salary > %@)", minimumSalary];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
    initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
[sortDescriptor release];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (array == nil)
{
    // Deal with error...
}
```

With NSFetchresultController

```
[[self managedObjectContext] fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"Employee" withPredicate:
    @"(lastName LIKE[c] 'Worsley') AND (salary > %@)", minimumSalary];
```

These examples are for Famous employee table. Translate the code as per your requirement. If you are unable to work around with this code for any reason, let me know..

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this code for fetching details and pass the object to Forgot class and show there.


-(User*)getUserCredentialDetails:(NSUInteger)mobilenumber
{

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mobilenumber = %d",mobileNumber];

    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSArray * resultArray = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    [request release];

    if (error != nil)
      {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

      }

    return [resultArray lastObject];

}
```